# Rails, Sintax error on Openshift deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openshift

I'm trying to push a Rails4 application into Openshift (where I have a  Ruby 2.0 Cartridge). During the deployment I get this error:

```
remote: Generating secret token
remote: Gemfile syntax error:
remote: /var/lib/openshift/551922844382eca634000057/app-root/runtime/repo/Gemfile:18:
remote: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end
remote: gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :x64_mingw, :mswin, :jruby]
```

This is the Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

if Gem::Version.new(Bundler::VERSION) < Gem::Version.new('1.5.0')
  abort "Redmine requires Bundler 1.5.0 or higher (you're using #{Bundler::VERSION}).\nPlease update with 'gem update bundler'."
end

gem "rails", "4.2.0"
gem "jquery-rails", "~> 3.1.1"
gem "coderay", "~> 1.1.0"
gem "builder", ">= 3.0.4"
gem "request_store", "1.0.5"
gem "mime-types"
gem "protected_attributes"
gem "actionpack-action_caching"
gem "actionpack-xml_parser"

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :x64_mingw, :mswin, :jruby]
gem "rbpdf", "~> 1.18.5"

# Optional gem for LDAP authentication
group :ldap do
  gem "net-ldap", "~> 0.3.1"
end

# Optional gem for OpenID authentication
group :openid do
  gem "ruby-openid", "~> 2.3.0", :require => "openid"
  gem "rack-openid"
end

platforms :mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw do
  # Optional gem for exporting the gantt to a PNG file, not supported with jruby
  group :rmagick do
    gem "rmagick", ">= 2.0.0"
  end

  # Optional Markdown support, not for JRuby
  group :markdown do
    gem "redcarpet", "~> 3.1.2"
  end
end

platforms :jruby do
  # jruby-openssl is bundled with JRuby 1.7.0
  gem "jruby-openssl" if Object.const_defined?(:JRUBY_VERSION) && JRUBY_VERSION < '1.7.0'
  gem "activerecord-jdbc-adapter", "~> 1.3.2"
end

# Include database gems for the adapters found in the database
# configuration file
require 'erb'
require 'yaml'
database_file = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "config/database.yml")
if File.exist?(database_file)
  database_config = YAML::load(ERB.new(IO.read(database_file)).result)
  adapters = database_config.values.map {|c| c['adapter']}.compact.uniq
  if adapters.any?
    adapters.each do |adapter|
      case adapter
      when 'mysql2'
        gem "mysql2", "~> 0.3.11", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
        gem "activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter", :platforms => :jruby
      when 'mysql'
        gem "activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter", :platforms => :jruby
      when /postgresql/
        gem "pg", "~> 0.17.1", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
        gem "activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter", :platforms => :jruby
      when /sqlite3/
        gem "sqlite3", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
        gem "activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter", "1.3.11", :platforms => :jruby
      when /sqlserver/
        gem "tiny_tds", "~> 0.6.2", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
        gem "activerecord-sqlserver-adapter", :platforms => [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
      else
        warn("Unknown database adapter `#{adapter}` found in config/database.yml, use Gemfile.local to load your own database gems")
      end
    end
  else
    warn("No adapter found in config/database.yml, please configure it first")
  end
else
  warn("Please configure your config/database.yml first")
end

group :development do
  gem "rdoc", ">= 2.4.2"
  gem "yard"
end

group :test do
  gem "minitest"
  gem "rails-dom-testing"
  gem "mocha"
  gem "simplecov", "~> 0.9.1", :require => false
  # For running UI tests
  gem "capybara"
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
  # building ffi 1.9.7 fails in Ubuntu: https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/414
  gem "ffi", "1.9.6"
end

local_gemfile = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "Gemfile.local")
if File.exists?(local_gemfile)
  eval_gemfile local_gemfile
end

# Load plugins' Gemfiles
Dir.glob File.expand_path("../plugins/*/{Gemfile,PluginGemfile}", __FILE__) do |file|
  eval_gemfile file
end
```

I guess it doesn't recognize the Ruby version or something similar.
How should I fix it?

---

UPDATE

I had to change into this:

```
platforms :jruby, :mingw, :mswin do
  gem 'tzinfo-data'
end
```

Comment: It seems somehow you're using Ruby in < 1.9.0 version. It doesn't support `key: value` hash syntax.

Comment: Change the hash syntax to the hashrocket format (:platforms => [...). I Think that should help.

Comment: I had to change the platforms row. First message updated.